# Node.js How to get image name from base64 string

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, base64

I want to get image name from base64 string to pass in **base64img** 
        I have used base64-img module 
        here is my route I am taking a base64 string from the mobile application and then 
        convert that base64 into an image and saving its path in MySQL database, I now 
        need image name as well so that every image will be saved with different 
        name *and kindly inspect my code for further improvements, as I am using 
        promises so is that correct way to query from DB, but I think there will be 
        another best way to handle chaining promises thanks* 
        I have elaborated all my problem is to get image name from base64 encoded 
        image 
        that is my route**

```
 router.post('/addProductOrService', (req, res) => {
        let pData = {
           // some data
        };
        // service data 
        let sData = {
           // some data
        };

        const qryp = 'insert into products set ?';
        const qrys = 'insert into services set ?';
        // here that base64-img starts 
        base64Img.img('data:image/png;base64,' + req.body.picture, 'public/productservices', 'imageName', function (err, filepath) {
             if (err) {
                 res.json({ status: 401, message: 'Error in base64' + err });
                 return;
             }
            Promise.using(mysql.getSqlConn(), conn => {
                if (req.body.isProduct == 1) {
                    pData.picture = filepath;
                    conn.query(qryp, pData).then(() => {
                        res.json({ status: 200, message: 'Product added successfully' });
                    }).catch(err => {
                        res.json({ status: 500, message: 'Error ' + err });
                    });
                } else {
                    sData.picture = filepath;
                    conn.query(qrys, sData).then(() => {
                        res.json({ status: 200, message: 'Service added successfully' });
                    }).catch(err => {
                        res.json({ status: 500, message: 'Error ' + err });
                    });
                }
            });
       }); // image 

    }
 });
});
```

Comment: Sorry you can't without some manipulation. You should pass the image name via some extra parameter.

Comment: Thanks @ChibuezeOpata